# virt-manager kvm modules are not available

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm

Fedora 16 latest updates running on a HP Mini 210 with an Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N550 @ 1.50GHz.

```
sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization
```

Only installed virt-viewer

```
sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization Platform
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Warning: Group virtualization does not have any packages.
Warning: Group Platform does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

After trying the above I am still getting the same message.

I have installed the virt-manager. When I try and create a new virtual machine I get the following warning:

> KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.

I have installed the following package:

```
qemu-kvm-0.15.1-4.fc16.x86_66
```

And loaded the kvm module:

```
lsmod | grep kvm
kvm                   406993  0
```

Not sure what package I am expected to install, or what kvm kernel module is not loaded?

Normally I use virtualbox without any problem. But I wanted to try and see if this virt-manager performs better.

Comment: "sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization " will this work on aws amazon linux  ec2 instance ??

Answer (score 4):

Also in my case (Fedora 16 32 bits) I've installed everything ...also I've activated bios visualization vt-x... cpu is compatible .. but the same error (KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed,or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.)

**Finaly I've executed manualy modprobe kvm_intel** and all done.

```
[root@monsterm ~]# grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority

lshw | grep vmx
[root@monsterm ~]# lshw | grep vmx
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm ida tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority cpufreq


# check kvm kernel modules
modprobe kvm_intel
lsmod | grep kvm

[root@monsterm ~]# lsmod | grep kvm*
kvm_intel             126289  0 
kvm                   356309  1 kvm_intel
```

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization
sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization Platform 
sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization Client
sudo yum groupinstall Virtualization Tools
```

*make sure to reboot after that installation is complete*

you can check service is started by issuing following command (it should return service is started)

```
service libvirtd status
```

Comment: That did not work. All it did was install the virt-viewer. Platform Group doesn't exist. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are more packages required than just `qemu-kvm`.

This will get you what you need.

`yum groupinstall Virtualization`

**Edit:**

To answer your question about your CPU and virtualization, run

```
$ egrep '^flags.*(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

If NOTHING is printed, your system does not support the relevant extensions. You can still use the QEMU/KVM, but the emulator will fall back to software virtualization, which is FAR FAR slower.

You should not have to manually load the kvm kernel module. Just start the libvirt service.

`service libvirtd start`

Now when you run `lsmod | grep kvm`, you should see

```
kvm
kvm_intel
```

If you don't see both modules, kvm is not installed correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The Atom N550 doesn't support virtualization extensions. I have noticed that when I start the libvirtd it doesn't automatically load the kvm module. However, I have to load the module myself .i.e modprobe kvm. In your option, does the software virtualization still give better performance than virtualbox?

Comment: Try to also load kvm_intel with `modprobe kvm_intel`

Comment: FATAL: Error inserting kvm_intel (/lib/modules/3.3.2-1.fc16.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko): Operation not supported. So I guess its back to virtualbox.

Comment: Note that AMD has KVM modules as well, load them with `modprobe kvm_amd`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VMware guest machine, so I checked at VMware Hardware Setting in Processor there's called Virtualization engine. It already sets Automatically but turns out that Automatically actually blocking my virtualization profile on VMware guest so I changed preferred mode to Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI and Voila problem solved !!

Answer (score -1):

I experienced same problem and after read a lot of guides of how to configure KVM, almost 24h later I realized that is necessary to Enable the Virtualization on BIOS... Uffff!!!